# Getting an error in my asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following error message.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  using System;
Line 2:  using System.Data;
Line 3:  using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: How about showing us some of the code. In particular, show the class declaration in codebehind, and show us the `Page` directive in the .aspx file.

Comment: I am trying to paste the code, but the code is over 600 characters long; so I will try to paste it in two pieces.

This is the only code I have written:

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class SqlConnectionDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = SqlConnection("Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=JobSearchManager;Integrated Security = SSPI");
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Agency", conn);

Comment: rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader;
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rdr != null)
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close;
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: The aspx page is:

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly what the error says:

Your .ASPx file Page header has 2 atributes related to your issue: CodeFile and Inherits. The file referenced in the CodeFile attribute must have a class with the same name defined in the Inherits attribute and this class must be a Page or a UserControl.

If this doesn't solve your problem. Let me know.

Comment: Andre has given you the correct answer, you need to take the time to understand what "CodeFile" and "Inherits" mean in the @Page directive.

Comment: Additionally, make sure no other pages (accidentally) try to inherit a class from the same code behind file.